# Purpose of const boost::shared_ptr<T>& as function argument?

Tags: c++, boost

I'm using a certain large and well-maintained open-source C++ library and came across a class definition having a constructor of the form

```
class SomeClass {
    SomeClass( const boost::shared_ptr<SomeOtherClass>& );
}
```

My question is: what's the point of passing a `const boost::shared_ptr<T>` by reference? Is there really a non-negligible amount of overhead associated with passing a `boost::shared_ptr<T>` by value, or is there some other kind of danger to passing a `boost::shared_ptr<T>` by value that I'm not aware of?

Comment: The more idiomatic way is to pass native data types by value and other things by const reference, from what I've seen at least. Bjarne mentions reference "worth it" with anything bigger than a couple of words in his Style and Technique FAQ.

Comment: @chris: Native or custom is irrelevant. What matters is the time taken to copy. An `int` wrapped in a `struct` is still probably best done by value.

Comment: @DeadMG, true, but if you're going to guess at sizes, then classes will most likely be big enough that it's worth it. Taking the time to check the size of each one you pass isn't worth the small amount of time saved.

Comment: It doesn't matter either way until you've profiled.  Until then it's religion, guesswork, and assumption.

Comment: @CrazyEddie: Not religion or guesswork, assumption I'll give you, but it's a good rule of thumb.  Rules of thumb are better in the general sense, unless your application's performance is so dreadfully important that profiling is a must.  Even then, the time difference between pass-by-ref and pass-by-value might or might not even show up on the radar, and even if the difference is significant, are you sure you'd know how to recognize the issue if you saw it without actually trying both ways?  The rule-of-thumb in this case is probably better to stick with in most cases.

Comment: @phonetagger - by your own admission it makes little difference most of the time and you don't really know which until you profile.  Deciding in the face of that to arbitrarily call something a "rule of thumb" (and at this point I don't even know which way you think is right) you pretty much need to enter into dogmatic showdown...since you can't actually show a reason why one is a better rule than the other.  That's more or less exactly what I meant by it being religion until you actually measure it.

Comment: @CrazyEddie: I guess I'd say "any reasonably good rule-of-thumb should work."  You can use Bjarne's rule of thumb (see http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#call-by-reference) or make up your own.  I don't see why you'd get all bent out of shape over this & try to call it religion & dogma; that's sort of inflamatory.  If you don't know or don't care to know an object's internal representation, using pass-by-ref will shield you from unwittingly copying multi-megabytes just to make a function call (I know that would blow most stacks, but work with me here.)

Comment: ...And of course write your contract with your user into your method signature: declare const ref’s if you have no business changing the caller’s object.  You can still copy the object internally if you need a modifiable copy of it, in which case you haven’t really lost much as compared to call-by-value.  BUT... If you do know an object’s internal representation and know it’s small (use your own judgement here, whatever you choose, and no, profiling isn’t generally necessary for this), and if you don’t need to change the caller’s copy of it, then you can choose pass-by-val.

Comment: ...A good rule of thumb is probably somewhere around 16 bytes (four 32-bit words) or so (pass-by-val below that & pass-by-ref above that), but that’s not a hard & fast boundary.  And short of profiling, you might also base your decision on how much you’ll be using the object that was passed... If your function is sort of unnaturally long and you’ll be referring to the object a lot, there is a small amount of indirection overhead that might be avoided by having a local direct-access copy of it, but even if your interface uses pass-by-const-ref,...

Comment: ...you can still choose to make a local copy of it for performance reasons if you’d like to avoid the indirection overhead.  Rules of thumb are not bad, and I agree that they shouldn’t be dogma, but there’s no reason to not have them.

Comment: @phonetagger - wow, and _I_ am getting bent out of shape??  I'm not going to read all that.  I'll simply respond to the first bit by wondering why you're arguing with me when you don't seem to be saying anything different from what I did: it doesn't matter until you profile.  You seem to care quite a bit about things you've said don't matter.

Comment: @CrazyEddie:  Ok, then you go ahead and pass all your native data types as const references and your complex data structures by value pending some future profiling activity, and let me know how it goes.  In most cases rules of thumb are better than profiling, because most projects don't warrant the effort of profiling.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Passing this by value is going to copy it which results in a reference count increment, synchronized across all threads.  Definitely non-negligible.

Comment: I would imagine it becomes very important to pass by value in a multi-threaded environment, where those effects are actually noticed.  Pass by reference and your shared pointer could be effectively deleted while you're executing the function you passed it to, since the reference doesn't count in the sharing scheme.

Answer (score 1):

Not only are you avoiding any (slight) overhead of copying a `shared_ptr` but you're also declaring your intent not to keep a copy of the pointer. I don't think you can make a copy of a `shred_ptr` without modifying it, and `const` would prevent that.

Comment: Indeed you can copy a `shared_ptr` without modifying it. Copying the `shared_ptr` doesn't mutate the source.

Comment: @DeadMG, but it does modify the pointer object itself. We're talking about `const shared_ptr<T>`, not `shared_ptr<const T>`. I must admit I've never tried it.

Comment: @MarkRansom You are forgetting that we are able to define const in C++ however we want. It just so happened that the people who made shared_ptr defined const as not modifying the contained object. There could have just as easily been const as you described, not being able to modify the container.

Comment: @EthanSteinberg: Actually, const on a shared_ptr doesn't prevent you from modifying the contained object, it does prevent you from modifying the container (the shared_ptr object), as in, you can't make it point to something else. (I may have misinterpreted you)

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Oops, mixing up const int* semantics and const shared_ptr semantics. Good catch.

Comment: Took me a while to understand what this answer was actually saying, but yeah, definitely wrong.

Comment: To all: I tested my assumptions and it turns out you were right and I was wrong. The `const` makes no difference to the ability to copy the pointer, nor does it affect the const-ness of the object pointed to. The only thing it affects is methods that modify the pointer directly, like `reset`.

Comment: You may have been thinking of auto_ptr.  That little abomination does need to be non-const to be "copied".

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to have a copy then why make a copy? It would be another question if they proceeded to copy it in the body anyway.