# Purpose of shared_ptr<T>&& as constructor argument

Tags: c++, constructor, c++11, shared-ptr, rvalue-reference

This question extends a previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458235/purpose-of-const-boostshared-ptrt-as-function-argument) discussing the usefulness of `boost::shared<T>&` as a constructor argument:

```
class SomeClass {  
    SomeClass( const boost::shared_ptr<SomeOtherClass>& );  
}
```

Would an rvalue reference argument in place of the `boost::shared_ptr<T>&` offer any advantage?

```
class SomeClass {  
    SomeClass( const boost::shared_ptr<SomeOtherClass>&& );  
}
```

In particular, for a multithreaded setting, would a constructor with an rvalue reference of shared_ptr type be any more useful then pass-by-value or pass-by-reference?

Comment: If you take an rvalue reference, you can _move_ the `shared_ptr` into an internal member rather than copying it. Copying a `shared_ptr` causes it to increment its reference count, which is quite a bit more expensive than one might initially think. Note what while copying a `shared_ptr` is thread-safe, moving one is not.

Answer (score 5):

`shared_ptr` isn't special.  The same rules apply to it as to pretty much any other object.  Would you ever make a const rvalue reference parameter?  I can't see any valid reason.  What about an rvalue reference of some other class?  Except in a class' own move constructor and move assignment operator, you should, for the most part, not take objects by rvalue reference.  If you need a copy of the object then you take it in by value, and move it, like this:

```
class SomeClass {
    std::shared_ptr<SomeOtherClass> myptr;
public:
    SomeClass(std::shared_ptr<SomeOtherClass> yourptr)
        :myptr(std::move(yourptr))
    {}
};
```

If you don't need a copy, then you take it in by const reference if your intent is just to examine it, or normal reference if you intend to modify it.

If you want to promise that you won't modify the object pointed to, then you can accept `const std::shared_ptr<const SomeOtherClass> &`, and that will work even if the argument doesn't have the inner const qualifier.

Comment: If you want to emphasize that you are taking ownership of something, I think an rvalue ref parameter is quite acceptable.

Comment: @Xeo: If you take an argument by value and move it, then you *are* taking ownership of it.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I think he rather meant that you want to force the callsite to give up ownership over the object.

Answer (score 1):

There's no purpose to a `const` rvalue. But taking by rvalue can enable quicker transfer of ownership, as only a swap is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's any such thing as a const rvalue reference and I don't know what it would mean.  By the time it got to the function and had a name it would be essentially the same thing as a const lvalue reference (if it has a name it's an lvalue is the rule).  You would not be allowed to move it.

I'm not sure what it would mean at the call site...if anything.  Certainly it could only serve to confuse the hell out of people and so is simply bad.

Frankly, I'd be a bit annoyed if that compiled.  I can't say it's illegal though.

Now, get rid of the const part and you've a different story.  Now you can "move" the shared_ptr.  I rather doubt though that shared_ptr has a move constructor, but maybe it does.  It would mean what moving always means: that the receiving entity MAY take over the supplied variable, possibly destroying it.

Comment: There is such a thing as a const rvalue reference, but it's pretty useless.